# Site stats of non-beta sites

Tags: discussion, site-stats

Is it possible to see stats for sites that are no longer in their beta (like [photo.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/))? If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the stats [Area 51 proposals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1265/photography-and-photographic-editing) show.

You can see most of them at https://stackexchange.com/sites. This list doesn't break users down by rep and doesn't show answers per question, but the rest are there.

Beyond that, you could write some [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/photography/queries) queries.

Comment: There are some brief stats there, but not as detailed as that of beta sites in Area 51. Writing custom queries in Data Explorer is a good idea. But I am still wondering why detailed stats are gone when a site goes out of its beta phase. Any reason for that?

Comment: @Meysam Which stats are you looking for? The A51 stats are important for sites while they're growing and working on ensuring that they're on the right track. A site that's no longer in beta doesn't need to worry about their stats quite the same way.